# Laravel 5.8 Save into database Mysql password with special characters not work

Tags: laravel, passwords, special-characters

if i recovery password with Laravel 5.8 and save a new password with special characters:

Ex: Stack1!

The reset is done but when i can to login give me a error password.

Why?

**UPDATE:**

Model config:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password){
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
}
```

ResetPasswords:

```
  $user->password = html_entity_decode($password);

        $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

        $user->save();

        event(new PasswordReset($user));
```

Comment: Did you change the password through the user interface or directly in your database?

Comment: through the user interface

Comment: You have to elaborate on your question, maybe you are not even hashing your password. Its hard to tell.

Comment: did you use Hash::make('yourpassword'); or bcrypt('yourpassword') or simply added it as plain text?

Comment: I have update the question. Thanks!